# How to Prevent instantiation of concrete classes?

Tags: java, design-patterns

Lets say I have a `Record` Interface and I can have N number of its concrete implementation classes eg. `PropertyRecords`,`LoanRecords` etc.How do I ensure there is no object of these N classes is created by client using new keyword?

Its quite easy if I have a single subclass;I can Make all the constructors package private;so that I can write a `Factory` class in the same package which will have a method which will be responsible for creating instances.But how to create a virtual `Factory` able to create several implementations of a single interface or abstract class.

Hope i am able to put myself correctly.Please ask if any clarification needed.

Thank you.

Comment: How does the package private solution (or similar, I wouldn't rely on package private if it's important, anyone can create a class in your package) not apply to the situation you're talking about? It's not clear from your question.

Comment: Are you looking for [Abstract Factory Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern)

Comment: What you're trying to do sounds a lot like an `enum`. Each `enum` member can be a subclass of the main `enum` class.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder package private solution will be suitable for only one class or two class because while returing the instance from factory i need to check for instance type eg. Property,Loan.Please Correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question: You want a class with some specific subclasses (whose instance numbers you could control with a factory class) and you want to prevent the creation of new subclasses from that class (whose instance numbers could not be controlled with a factory, because you don't know them before). Is that right?

Comment: @DanglingPiyush: I don't see what the number of classes has to do with it at all, perhaps a code example demonstrating the problem would help.

Comment: @tobias_k No I dont want to stop client from creating subclasses of my concrete classes I just want to ensure that noone can create an  instance of my concrete class using new() keyword and also I want to provide a virtual Factory which can on the fly create instance of my concrete implementations no matter how many are there.

Comment: Maybe you can say more clearly WHO should be able to create new instances (using the factory), and HOW exactly he should be able to do this. Should he be able to call `LoanRecord r = Factory.createLoanRecord()` or `Record r = Factory.createLoanRecord()`, or `LoanRecord r = Factory.createRecord(LoanRecord.class)` or something entirely different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you would want this, but your `Factory` class can use reflection to create instances like this:

```
public class RecordFactory {
    public Record newInstance(Class<? extends Record> klass, Object... args) {
        Constructor[] ctors = klass.getDeclaredConstructors();
        // find the right constructor here..
        return ctor.newInstance(args);
    }
}
```

Then your clients can create instances like:

```
RecordFactory.newInstance(Loan.class, ...);
```

Comment: OP says Record is an interface, would it make more sense if : public Record newInstance(Class<? implements Record> klass, Object... args) {

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure I understand what you're trying to achieve (comment on this is not), but here are my thoughts:

1. Sounds like what you really want is to implement the Flyweight design pattern (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern).
2. If you really want to implement this as you describe it (again, under the assumption that I understood correctly), the following should work:

   ```
   public class Record {
       private static final int MAX_INSTANCES = 20;
       private static volatile int instanceCounter = 0;

       private Record() {
           if (instanceCounter >= MAX_INSTANCES)
               throw new RuntimeException("max instances exceeded");

           instanceCounter ++;
       }
   }
   ```